# Could a body of moving water be a colour other than blue?

Tags: geology

In my made up world, I have an onyx coloured river but I am not sure if it would work.

Edit*

I want to have black water where the river used to be an old lava bed so the lava rock at the bottom would cause the water to look black but it is still clear water?

Comment: do you need the water in the river to be black or is it enough that the river appears black to an onlooker?

Comment: I kind of want the river to appear black but when separated I to smaller portions just clear water.

Comment: Why can't you just have it be a shallow river, and the bottom of the river be made up of material with a specific color? When you take the water out, it's obviously normal water, but when it's in that spot it can be whatever color you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help I kind of come up with an idea to have it work out.

Comment: Water is blue due to how it disperses light.   If it contains a dissolved mineral that asorbs all light spectrums you will get the black river while the wster is clear.   However this is big body of water...many rivers arent really blue as there isnt enough depth to cause the light dispersal.   Some dissolved mystery element in the water might work as a semi handwavy but semi believable reasoning

Comment: In [The Narrative of Arthur Gordon Pym of Nantucket](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Narrative_of_Arthur_Gordon_Pym/Chapter_18) by [Edgar Allan Poe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Allan_Poe), the water looks peculiar indeed. _"It was not colourless, nor was it of any one uniform colour- presenting to the eye, as it flowed, every possible shade of purple; like the hues of a changeable silk."_

Answer (score 5):

Pure water is colorless. What gives a body of water one color or another is whatever is in that water, whether dissolved, suspended or swimming in it.

That's why we get such a variety of different colours showing up naturally on Earth. Just take a look at the [Yellow River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_River), which is only debatably yellow on some parts of it. Look at all the pictures of that wiki and see how varied it is.

You may be even more interested, though, in a river in Brazil called [Rio Negro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rio_Negro_(Amazon)). Translated to English, that's literally "Black River". From the wiki:

> The dark color comes from humic acid due to an incomplete breakdown of phenol-containing vegetation from sandy clearings.

You could justify your water's blackness with some chemical compound present in, or deriving from the lava, or the chemical interaction of something in it with the water.

I read the comments and I see that you want it to be clear in small quantities. IRL if you take a cup of water out of a colored water body such as a lake or a river, it will generally seem clear. In order for it to be dark such as in Rio Negro you need to have some depth. The water will look clear on the margins of such bodies.

Comment: Well, what gives water color in quantity is also how the light refracts in it. That's why it looks blue.

Comment: Pure water is [slightly blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_of_water).

Comment: 'detabably' is my new favourite word

Comment: I recall my inlaws sending pictures of *7 color waters* or something like that, famous for the body of water having many different colors visible in one shot. I think it was [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiuzhaigou)

Answer (score 1):

If the water is clear enough and the bed black enough a river could indeed look as though it were black, another solution would be having particles of a very light absorbing material floating in it, but that would mean that water taken away from the river would also be darkened, at least a bit, unless these particles for some reason remain in the river.

Answer (score 1):

Your question:

> I want to have black water where the river used to be an old lava bed so the lava rock at the bottom would cause the water to look black but it is still clear water?

That's not really a question, you just take the question mark off the end and there's your answer.

"rock at the bottom would cause the water to look black". Yep, especially in low light.

"but it is still clear"—Do you mean when you lift some water out of the river, you can still see through it? That's fine, that's just normal water.

Comment: I’ve seen that, in Maui.